# How to format a date from the date object in `ng-model`

Tags: angularjs, date

I am getting date values from the `ng-model` from the controller. I would like to format the date as `10-22-2013` But in the output i am getting the date format as `10/22/2013`

what is the correct way to format the date here?

js :

```
angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
     .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.example = {
         value: new Date(2013, 9, 22)
       };
     }]);
```

html :

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <label for="exampleInput">Pick a date </label>
     <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" 
       placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2013-01-01" max="2013-12-31" required />
   <div role="alert">
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
         Required!</span>
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.date">
         Not a valid date!</span>
    </div>

</form>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IaQf2djrteEQqlgEnVx9?p=preview)

Comment: In the Punker the value in the textbox is appearing as `10-22-2013`. Not `10/22/2013`. Isn't that what you want it to be?

Comment: Yes roy. if you have any different answer please post here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using purely HTML5 there is no answer to your question. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/6138713).

> There is no way possible to change the format
>
> We have to differentiate between the over the wire format and the
> browser's presentation format.
>
> Wire format The HTML5 date input specification [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/6138713) refers to the
> RFC3339 specification [2](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), which specifies a full-date format equal
> to: yyyy-mm-dd. See section 5.6 of the RFC3339 specification for more
> details.
>
> Presentation format Browsers are unrestricted in how they present a
> date input. At the time of writing Chrome has the most extensive date
> support [3]. It displays a date picker using the user's local calendar
> format. Opera (v10.6+) also displays a date picker, but shows the date
> in the wire format. Other browsers, such as Firefox 44.0.2 and
> Internet Explorer 9/10/11 display a text input field with the wire
> format.
>
> References http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339
> https://plus.google.com/102860501900098846931/posts/hTcMLVNKnec

I suggest using [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It has a neat load of modules that makes everything easy for angular.

The markup in the view would look like this:

```
<p class="form-group">
    <label>Result</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="date" />
</p>
```

And on the controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DateParserDemoCtrl', function ($scope, uibDateParser) {
  $scope.format = 'MM-dd-yyyy';
  $scope.date = new Date();
});
```